# Submit button access denied cannot get any result

Tags: android, layout, emulation

I have a problem with my android project. I cannot get access to my button. I have attach my class code==http://pastebin.com/A5ZTBkhd. Please anyone help me.
Here is  my code -
    package com.droid.androiddoctor;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidDoctorMainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_doctor_main);


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_android_doctor_main, menu);
        return true;
    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.btnSubmit:

            String e="hello";
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Dang it!");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
            break;
        }
    }


}
```

.Here is my code.when i push submit nothing happens. and the xml file is====

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >








    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        androi:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnExit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please be as clear as you can when you are asking questions. First and an easy step would be copying your code here instead of linking it. Second step is a bit harder, narrow down your question and be more specific.

Comment: here is my code.when i push submit nothing happens.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


   

  



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnExit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit" />

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not set the listener for your widgets at all. Try this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_doctor_main);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this)
}
```

I would suggest you to go through [Android's UI Guide.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)

Comment: no . i have a layout in which  there is a button. that i want to click. not the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu). i have nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't implement OnClickListener like that, try to add it like this in your class:

```
public class AndroidDoctorMainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_doctor_main);
 Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
 Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
//your code for click on this button
}});

button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
//your code for this button 

//or if you just want to exit from activity, just call:
finish();
}});

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    }


}
```